# Adding class to filtered Isotope items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

My goal is to add a class to all filtered Isotope items.

I am using the `getFilteredItemElements` functionality from the Isotpe documentation.

I set a variable equal to all the filtered items as below:

```
var filteredItems = $grid.isotope('getFilteredItemElements');
```

This returns me an array of elements:

```
[div.grid-item.p-1.summer.value1.none, div.grid-item.p-1.summer.value1.none, div.grid-item.p-1.summer.value3.none]
```

I then wanna add a class to the items in the array by using jQuery `.each`.

```
     filteredItems.each(function(){
        this.addClass('');
     });
```

But the browser returns `Uncaught TypeError: filteredItems.each is not a function`

Am I writing a each function incorrect or is it not possible to use `.each` in this case?

Comment: That looks like a basic array.  So you don't need jquery to do that.  Use `forEach` instead of `each` and use `this.classList.add('')`

Comment: everything is written in detail here - https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do

```
[...filteredItems].forEach(elm => elm.classList.add(''));
```